# AutoMapper Factory Methods and Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

**The Question**: How do I get a value from `HttpContext.User.Claims` into a ConstructUsing call? Or more broadly, how do I construct something via a factory method when I have a dependency on `HttpContext.User.Claims`?

---

I'm trying to set up an AutoMapper mapping against a factory method. This has lead me to `ConstructUsing()`:

```
CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
             .ConstructUsing((src, context) => DestinationType.Factory.Create(
                 src.SomeProperty,
                 "RUT-OH!", // This value comes from HttpContext.User.Claims
                 ...
             ));
```

However, the second property comes from `HttpContext.User.Claims`

I've created a value resolver to pull this out of the context:

```
public class SecretIdResolver : IValueResolver<SourceType, DestinationType, string>
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public SecretIdResolver(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string Resolve(SourceType source, DestinationType destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "SecretId").Value;
    }
}
```

But there doesn't seem to be any way to leverage the Value Resolver when using ConstructUsing.

Comment: AFAIK, `Automapper` was invented to mapping between objects, and there shouldn't be other dependencies among them.
For the sake of simplicity, may I suggest to separate mapper, and factory to 2 distinct things ? That's really clearer for maintenance in the long rung. A factory class and pass the instance needed to be map in, just as simple as that.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Answer (score 1):

Lucian's comment worked as a feasible alternative.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

The controller has access to the HttpContext and can provide the additional contextual values to the Map method.